# What is the best way to update (not replace) LongListSelector data

Tags: xaml, sorting, windows-phone-8, observablecollection, longlistselector

I am digging the answer for days now and I am still not fully satisfied with the ways I found. I can't believe there is no easy answer for to update (not replace completely) LongListSelector data instead of just replacing or writing some sort of sophisticated code. Is there any other choice where UI will be updated except of replacing the items source? Solution needs to be capable of items sorting (on collection side) :/

What I've tried so far

- List - caused scrolling to top
- ObservableCollection - does not provide filtering and sorting, so that needs to be handled manually each time data are about to change
- MyToolkit.Collections.ObservableCollectionView - worked well except of sorting (sort was based on sub property - eg. Device.Data.Index)
- CollectionViewSource - does not work with LLS

I'm really wasted right now... Any ideas? :-)